# HTML5 video Uncaught TypeError: .play is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, zurb-foundation

I have a problem with video autoplay after buttonc click which opens foundation modal with video to be played. When i click on button to open modal with video, it opens but video do not start playing.

*In console i get Uncaught TypeError: **.play is not a function** error*

Opening modal button:

```
<div data-open="movieModal" id="movieModalOpenMedium">Open</div>
```

Video modal:

```
<div class="reveal full" id="movieModal" data-reveal data-reset-on-close="true">

<video id="company-movie" controls>
    <source src="/video/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And script looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// var movie = document.getElementById('company-movie');
var movie = $('#company-movie').get(0);
$('#movieModalOpenMedium').click(function(){
    movie.play();
})
```

})

**#company-movie** element is seen correctly in DOM however i cannot play it in any way.

I have tried with:

1. $('#company-movie').play() - **JQuery Object does not have play() method** so for sure it will not work
2. $('#company-movie').get(0).play();
3. $('#company-movie')[0].play();

but neither of these ways works.

I was also trying to do this without jQuery this way:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
var movie = document.getElementById('company-movie');

document.getElementById("movieModalOpenMedium").addEventListener("click", function(){
    movie.play();
});
```

})

but it also does not work.

I would be grateful for any help with it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try  `$('#company-movie')[0].play();` or `$('#company-movie').get(0).play();`

Comment: I tried it and it does not work. Still .play is not a function in console

Comment: Are you calling console.log(); or is the error just thrown?  If calling make sure you have the semi colon.

Comment: i was calling it. Ok i have changed to semicolon.

Comment: And, do you still that error?  Does your content play?

Comment: I still have .play() is not a function error. Video still does not play automatically.

Comment: It works. I accidentally duplicated id and movie could not be played...